# Macbook pro - does time machine restore to original state or just add removed files?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, time-machine, backup, restore

Macbook pro OS X 10.9
If I backup using time machine and 3 months later decide to restore it back because I have a virus, would it be able to eliminate the virus? Also does time machine delete all the new files i've added since then?

Answer (score 1):

If you believe your Mac has a virus or any kind of malware you should clean your Mac using a piece of software designed to remove malware. Time Machine isn't intended to be used to remove malware. There is nothing to stop a piece of malware from infecting your Time Machine backups.